# How to add multiple event listeners with selectors in one element?

Tags: javascript, dom

Here is What I have now
I was trying to make an existing Jquery code into plain JS

```
var todoList = document.getElementById('todo-list');
  todoList.addEventListener('change',this.toggle.bind(this),true);
  todoList.getAttribute('.toggle');
  todoList.addEventListener('dblclick', this.edit.bind(this),true);
  todoList.getAttribute('label');
  todoList.addEventListener('keyup', this.editKeyup.bind(this),true);
  todoList.getAttribute('.edit');
  todoList.addEventListener('focusout', this.update.bind(this),true);
  todoList.getAttribute('.edit');
  todoList.addEventListener('click', this.destroyCompleted.bind(this),true);
  todoList.getAttribute('.destroy');
```

Comment: Isn't it working ?

Comment: Nope i dont know why. I have the sample jquery code here

Comment: $('#todo-list')
    .on('change', '.toggle', this.toggle.bind(this))
    .on('dblclick', 'label', this.edit.bind(this))
    .on('keyup', '.edit', this.editKeyup.bind(this))
    .on('focusout', '.edit', this.update.bind(this))
    .on('click', '.destroy', this.destroy.bind(this));
  },

Comment: What you were trying to do is called event delegation, it's baked into jquery and not easily done in vanilla JS, so your confusion makes sense ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is event delegation, to have this work in vanilla JS you need to write up a little function by yourself.

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.on = function(event, selector, handler) {
  this.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
    let target = e.target;
    if (typeof(selector) === 'string') {
      while (!target.matches(selector) && target !== this) {
        target = target.parentElement;
      }

      if (target.matches(selector))
        handler.call(target, e);
    } else {
      selector.call(this, e);
    }
  });
};
```

You can then use this to handle your events. I don't have your Markup or the functions you are calling, but this should do the trick!

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.on = function(event, selector, handler) {
  this.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
    let target = e.target;
    if (typeof(selector) === 'string') {
      while (!target.matches(selector) && target !== this) {
        target = target.parentElement;
      }

      if (target.matches(selector))
        handler.call(target, e);
    } else {
      selector.call(this, e);
    }
  });
};


const todoList = document.getElementById('todo-list');

todoList.on('change', '.toggle', this.toggle.bind(this));
todoList.on('dblclick', 'label', this.edit.bind(this));
todoList.on('keyup', '.edit', this.editKeyup.bind(this));
todoList.addEventListener('focusout', '.edit', this.update.bind(this));
todoList.addEventListener('click', '.destroy', this.destroyCompleted.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks for this mate, I will study this one first and apply it in my code. Have a blessed time.

Comment: No problem! If you do get it to work, please upvote my answer too ;-)

Comment: Its working. Awesome this kind of stuff is really helpful for me since im still a beginner

Answer (score 0):

This works fine, you can run and check it here.

```js
mousemove = () => console.log('mousemove');
dblclick = () => console.log('dblclick');
click = () => console.log('click');


var todoList = document.getElementById('todo-list');
  todoList.addEventListener('dblclick', dblclick.bind(this), true);
  todoList.addEventListener('click', click.bind(this), true);
  todoList.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove.bind(this), true);
```

```html
<div id="todo-list" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: yellow;"></div>
```

Comment: Im suprised this one worked. But still my code wont function

Comment: Just try this way, instead of `this.functionname.bind(this)`, just call `functionname.bind(this)`

Comment: And why you're simply getting the `getAttribute(X)` and not using it at all ?

Comment: Your convertion from jquery code to javascript is wrong. Checkout jQuery API here http://api.jquery.com/on/ . 2nd param for `on()` is selector, but you didn't do that way in the converted code.

Comment: I have my functions inside the main object.

Comment: Thats the code I have confusion in Jquery is the on()  2nd parameter selector Tried converting it my way doesnt work at all.